# How do I make react router v6 load elements without having to manualy refresh the url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I send the user to a URL (in this case /login and /signup and then back to /)
the elements on my page don't load automatically by entering the URL, I instead have to manually refresh in order for the content to load.

This is my index.js which handles the routes (with react router v6)

```
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import Footer from "./components/footer/footer";

import Home from "./pages/home/home";
import Login from "./pages/user/login/login";
import Signup from "./pages/user/signup/signup";

ReactDOM.render(
<div>
<Navbar />
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
<Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
<Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
 <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
 </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
  <Footer />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is an example of what happens when I send the user to /login with the use of the Link component that I am importing through React-router.
[Before refreshing the URL  on /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlyNL.jpg)

I then have to manually reload the page by pressing the reload button, only after doing so the content will load.
[After refreshing the URL on /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2sb0.jpg)

the same applies if I try to go back to the homepage using the Link component
[Before refreshing on the URL /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzoD1.jpg)

I then have to reload in order to remove the login box
[After refreshing on the URL /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V36mJ.jpg)

Comment: Your code seem to be fine, the only thing that looks not at it's place is the path on index. Index doesn't take path. try this instead
<Route index element={<Home />} />

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the same behavior. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sea-13qxi) (try it and look at home.js)

You don't seem to be using the page navigation correctly. The most react way is to use the `useNavigation()` hook.

Answer (score 0):

If navigation is working but the routes aren't then I suspect you are rendering them into separate routers. I notice you render the `Navbar` ***outside*** your `BrowserRouter`, and since navigation is working and updating the URL in the address bar is fairly safe to assume those links are correctly wrapped in a router. You'd see an invariant warning/error otherwise.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Navbar /> // <-- must have another router if it is working
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    <Footer />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

You should have only one router wrapping the app and providing the routing context to all `Routes`, `Route`, `Navigate`, `Link`, etc... components.

Remove any extraneous routers in other components, like `NavBar`, and move them all to be within the `BrowserRouter` you are rendering here.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```